# how does tracking pre- regulator work?

Tags: linear-regulator

[image: lm338 pre regulator]

How much voltage does the first lm338 drop ?
How does it actually track the voltage, I thought there should be 1.25 V across adj and output?
I am not able to understand the logic of using the pre regulator, does it equally distribute power dissipation?
Can anybody explain this with an example of input voltages, current draw and output voltages on the two regulators?

I have searched hard and was not able to find an adequate answer.

Comment: In the future, please capitalize your sentences as well as the [first-person pronoun, "I"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7986).

Comment: i will do my best to maintain my grammar next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the LM338 data sheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm138.pdf, you'll find the standard circuit on page 7.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftsuWM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit works by changing the output so that the voltage aross R1 stays fixed at 1.25 volts. Then (assuming no significant diversion of current by the Vadj pin), the voltage out is (1 + R2/R1) x 1.25 volts.

So, let's start by assuming that the right-hand regulator has some output output VO. Then , looking at the resistors R1 and R2, the left-hand regulator (the preregulator) will have its output, call it V2, set so that (V2 - VO) x (R1 / R1 + R2) = 1.25 volts. It's just like the standard circuit except that the preregulator is referenced to the primary regulator rather than ground.

For R1 and R2 in the schematic, 1 + R2 / R1 = 1 + 720 / 240 = 1 + 3 = 4. So the preregulator will maintain V2 at VO + 5 volts.

At this point, you are probably deeply suspicious. How, after all, can you be certain that the main regulator is giving the correct output? The whole thing forms a vicious circle, right? If the main regulator is off, the preregulator is off, and it makes your head hurt, right? The secret is the presence of C1. This makes the preregulator just a little slower than the main regulator. So the preregulator always provides 5 volts more than the output, but doesn't respond quite as fast. This allows the main regulator to do its' thing without causing the whole circuit to start oscillating.

Comment: thank you the explanation was very clear. I will be making a lab supply out of this circuit.

Comment: also do you think its possible to convert the pre-regulator so that i can regulate current too any tips ? on how to do that (without negative voltage)

Comment: Please read the data sheet.

Comment: The secret is the presence of C1 or C2 ?

Comment: Please explain in more detail why C1 and C2 are the "secret".

Comment: I'm not seeing any such secret (output regulator always provides the expected voltage, the preregulator reduces power dissipation) but you might want to address the author of the answer in question by adding an @ in front of their name and adding a comment. The space you used is reserved for answers, not requests for clarification etc.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast As new user Photifere tried to "comment" in an answer: are you sure it's C1 that's the secret, and not C2? I suspect C1 is just regular decoupling.

Comment: Hi Photifere, welcome to EE.SE! I assume you tried to comment on WhatRoughBeast's answer, which states that "C1 is the secret", but you wonder if that should actually be C2. If so, I share your suspicion! The space you have used to post your question is intended for answers only, and it will probably be deleted. Sadly, new users [don't have the privilege of commenting on other answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), but if you keep contributing you will earn that privilege soon enough! For now, I have added a comment to WhatRoughBeast's answer to relay your question :)

Comment: Y;All: I've moved Photifere's answer here and all related comments so they will make sense. Someone may wish to flag these for deletion at some later date. Or not.